# Mysql Join Query optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, optimization

Hello i am trying to run this select statement using this query and it is taking over 2 hours to run. I have set up all the index's to be correct. But it still takes forever is there something i am missing or a more efficient way of joining tables together that will speed this query up?

I have indexes set up for all items being joined together and they are the same length and data type.

```
SELECT 
    p.sap_article_id, 
    p.numeric_line_code, 
    p.uag_linecode,  
    p.uag_partnum,   
    p.part_description, 
    p.jobber_price, 
    p.jobber_core, 
    p.discount1,  
    p.discount2, 
    p.uom, 
    p.product_category, 
    w.as400_warehouse,   
    w.atp_qty, 
    p.updated,  
    t.regular_discount     
FROM part p 
        LEFT JOIN tabjbmaw t ON t.accountnum        = '73050'
                            AND p.numeric_line_code = t.numeric_line_code 
                            AND p.sub_code          = t.sub_code    
        JOIN warehouse w ON w.sap_article_id = p.sap_article_id;

+----+-------------+-----------+------+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys                                    | key                   | key_len | ref                              | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | part      | ALL  | PRIMARY,sap_article,part_sap_article_id_fk       | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                             | 389309 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | warehouse | ref  | article                                          | article               | 130     | inventory.part.sap_article_id    |      5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tabjbmaw  | ref  | numeric_line_code_idx,subcode_idx,accountnum_idx | numeric_line_code_idx | 5       | inventory.part.numeric_line_code |     19 |             |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
```

Thank you for your help

```
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                       | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| sap_article_id              | varchar(24)  | NO   | PRI |                     |                             |
| sap_brand_id                | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| uag_partnum                 | varchar(20)  | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| uag_linecode                | varchar(5)   | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| cag_partnum                 | varchar(20)  | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| cag_linecode                | varchar(5)   | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| product_category_legacy     | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| part_description            | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| abc_indicator               | varchar(8)   | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| pack_code                   | varchar(8)   | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| case_qty                    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| per_car_qty                 | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| uom                         | varchar(6)   | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| upc_code                    | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| jobber_price                | float(14,4)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| jobber_core                 | float(14,4)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| date_last_price_change      | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| weight                      | float(14,4)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| weight_unit                 | varchar(6)   | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| dimension_type              | varchar(6)   | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| length                      | float(14,4)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| width                       | float(14,4)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| height                      | float(14,4)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| updated                     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0                   |                             |
| superseded_sap_article_id   | varchar(24)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| last_updated                | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| hour_updated                | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| discount1                   | float        | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| discount2                   | float        | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| product_category            | varchar(3)   | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| superseded_part_number      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| sub_code                    | varchar(3)   | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| date_effective_price_change | date         | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| numeric_line_code           | varchar(3)   | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| list                        | float        | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: What kind of JOIN do you want on the warehouse table? Have you tried moving '73050' = tabjbmaw.accountnum to a WHERE clause?

Comment: No, that would be a terrible mistake to remove that statement from the LEFT JOIN part. First of all the optimizer works the same in JOIN and WHERE clauses, and second a filter inserted to a WHERE clause makes the associated table  INNER joined, which is incorrect in this case because he wants an OUTER join.

Comment: we need empty values back in the discount is not there so moving it to the end doesn't help us. it needs to stay in there

Comment: @ITroubs Its a left outer join not an inner join, moving the check to the where would yield a different result.

Comment: Hmm right i see my mistake

Comment: habe you tried moving the tabjbmaw join into the select part as a subselect?

Comment: Adding a filter to the `parts` table would help.  Also, does `sap_article_id` really _need_ to be a `VARCHAR`?  That's a bad data type for a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have indexes set up for all items being joined together

Yes, but I am guessing from the names of the indexes that each index only has one field.

Let's look at a few columns in the describe.

```
| table     | possible_keys                                    | key                   
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------+----------------
| part      | PRIMARY,sap_article,part_sap_article_id_fk       | NULL                  
| warehouse | article                                          | article               
| tabjbmaw  | numeric_line_code_idx,subcode_idx,accountnum_idx | numeric_line_code_idx
```

It can use an index for numeric_line_code, subcode, and accountnum, but there are only three indexes each with one of the fields, and no index which has all the fields.  You are making the optimizer choose one of the one field indexes, instead of providing one index it can use for all three fields.

Add an index on table tabjbmaw with the three fields numeric_line_code, subcode, and accountnum.

Comment: how fast was it after you added the new index?

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Sebas answer, you should select tabjbmaw first:

```
SELECT 
    p.sap_article_id, 
    p.numeric_line_code, 
    p.uag_linecode,  
    p.uag_partnum,   
    p.part_description, 
    p.jobber_price, 
    p.jobber_core, 
    p.discount1,  
    p.discount2, 
    p.uom, 
    p.product_category, 
    w.as400_warehouse,   
    w.atp_qty, 
    p.updated,  
    t.regular_discount     
FROM tabjbmaw t
        LEFT JOIN parts p ON p.numeric_line_code = t.numeric_line_code 
                             AND p.sub_code       = t.sub_code    
        JOIN warehouse w ON w.sap_article_id = p.sap_article_id
WHERE t.accountnum = '73050'
;
```

Comment: if so that would be a very bad functional mistake from him :D But I agree with you it seems more logical

Comment: This will, of course, give different results, since it will miss any parts which do not match the join with tabjbmaw.  Also, it includes tabjbmaw records which do not match, when that was not part of the result before.  Maybe changing LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN would remove the missing parts, but not introduce missing tabjbmaw records.

Comment: This will not produce the same results as the original query.  The `LEFT` table here is `tabjbmaw`, not `parts` as in the original query.  Also, I don't think this would make much of a difference; it would still have to do a full table scan on `parts`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put your Left Join into the SELECT part as a Subselect. That 'may' speed things up a little.

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.sap_article_id, 
    p.numeric_line_code, 
    p.uag_linecode,  
    p.uag_partnum,   
    p.part_description, 
    p.jobber_price, 
    p.jobber_core, 
    p.discount1,  
    p.discount2, 
    p.uom, 
    p.product_category, 
    w.as400_warehouse,   
    w.atp_qty, 
    p.updated,  
    (SELECT t.regular_discount FROM tabjbmaw t WHERE t.accountnum = '73050' AND p.numeric_line_code = t.numeric_line_code AND p.sub_code = t.sub_code LIMIT 1)    
FROM 
    part p 
    JOIN warehouse w ON w.sap_article_id = p.sap_article_id;
```

Comment: This only allows one result from `tabjbmaw`, but the original query allows for multiple.  Also, `JOIN`s are almost always faster than subqueries.